# Free Transform tool activated by button

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to push a button on the excel sheet which will change the mouse to the free transform tool and then allow me to draw on the excel sheet. Is that possible?
I make an example to append scribble tool example instead a free transform

`Sub cButton_Click()
Application.CommandBars("Drawing").Controls("AutoShapes").Controls("Lines").Controls("Scribble").Execute
End Sub`

Comment: you seem to have the code. Be clear on what you need. If you want the Freeform instead of scribble....change the control and execute as before

Comment: I haven't the code yet. I find the different control like 'scribble' (the example above) but what i need is free transform control

Comment: I am not sure about a free transform control... But there is a Freeform controls which lets you scribble an area.

Comment: oh thanks. by the way, how to set the TakeFocusOnClick property of the CommandButton to FALSE? 
The Execute command does not pause so the following code is executed straight away.

Comment: Thses activex objects has an Ole Object property., The take focus property should be in there some where